# SQL - How would I select data involving multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

RDMS: MySQL

I'm designing a private messaging thread system and have the following schema laid out for the messaging system (simplified). I need to select every conversation that an account with a known ID (we'll say '1') is in, the last message that was sent in the conversation, and the username of the other account that account '1' is chatting with. Grouped by the conversation id. (imagine an inbox page like Facebook has)

My SQL knowledge is limited (I'm going to spend the weekend advancing it) but it the meantime does anyone have a query that would get the job done?

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need more info.

Schema 
[image]

EDIT: I believe I may have found a solution (still needs proper testing).
I'm still accepting answers as I'm not sure this is the best route to go yet. I've reviewed the current answers posted and they are getting me in the right direction but so far aren't returning the right results.

Here's what I've come up with.

```
SELECT account_has_conversations.account_id, messages.*, account.username FROM messages, account, account_has_conversations WHERE account_has_conversations.conversation_id IN

(
SELECT account_has_conversations.conversation_id FROM account_has_conversations WHERE account_has_conversations.account_id = '1'
)

AND account_has_conversations.account_id != '1' AND account_has_conversations.account_id = account.account_id
AND account_has_conversations.conversation_id = messages.conversation_id
GROUP BY account_has_conversations.conversation_id
```

(I probably should have created some aliases haha)

Comment: You should use [JOIN](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) and [GROUP BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm)

Comment: The potential solution I came up with, works great except the most recent message sent is not being shown (which I need). It seems to be showing the first message from the thread.

Comment: @thefakeslimshady check my answer - you need to partition the joined table by timestamp descending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't have any text fields in any of the tables in your pictured schema - so I don't know where you're storing the actual message content or how to retrieve it.  That said, this query should work for you and you can just add the field that you need.

This will get you the username, the last message received, and the sending username for all of the selected user's conversations.  I will ASSUME the message content is in the messages table and is stored in a field called "message_text":

```
DECLARE @AccountID int = 1 //For testing, but this should be parameterized


SELECT  A.username as [User],
    A2.username as [SendingUser]
    M.message_text as [LastMessage]
FROM account A
JOIN account_has_conversations AHC
    ON A.account_id = AHC.account_id
JOIN conversation C
    ON AHC.conversation_id = C.conversation_id
JOIN
    (
        Select 
        sender_account_id,
        conversation_id,
        message_text,
        row_number() over(partition by conversation_id order by time_sent desc) as rn 
        FROM messages 
    ) as M
    ON C.conversation_id = M.conversation_id
    AND M.sender_account_id <> @AccountID //This prevents a circular join in case the last message was sent by the user.  You may not need this, but it's impossible to tell based on the information you provided.
JOIN account A2
    ON M.sender_account_id = A2.account_ID
WHERE rn = 1
AND A.account_id = @AccountID
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this, but maybe this will get you in the right direction.

```
Select m.* 

from account a
inner join account_has_conversation ahc
on (a.account_id = account_id)
inner join messages m
on (ahc.conversation_id = m.conversation_id)

where a.account_id = 1
```

I would add:

- Your conversation table doesn't really seem to have any value.
- Group By is great, but you're going to need to squeeze all your results down as well. By that I mean that if you want to squish ten rows into one (grouping by one of the columns where all the rows have the same value in that column), you'll need to have all the other columns in an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.username, m.*, c.* FROM account a, messages m, conversation c 
WHERE a.account_id = m.sender_account_id AND m.conversation_id = c.conversation_id
```

Comment: This should return all of the conversations - not just the last line.  You need to row over partition ordering by ID or timestamp descending - and filter by row number = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new schema as below.
`messages(msg_id, con_id, message, time_sent, status)`

`acc(acc_id, username)`

`con(con_id)`

`conrel(con_id, acc_id)`

(typing from phone so ignore any smaller mistakes).

`SELECT distinct msg.message, conrel.con_id, acc.username FROM messages AS msg INNER JOIN conrel ON conrel.con_id = msg.con_id INNER JOIN acc ON conrel.acc_id=acc.acc_id where conrel.con_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT con_id FROM connrel WHERE acc_id=1) ORDER BY msg.time_sent DESC`

The solution can further be improved or changed according to needs. Plus remember to use coma separated result of INNER query above instead as INNER queries are slower but when they are passed with IDs like 1,4,5 they become fast.